# ARM bit numbering Hardware Design

Tags: arm

When I connect a NOR Flash to an ARM processor, for example, do I connect, for example, A0 to A0 (and D0 to D0) like a PowerPC, or A0 to A23 (and D0 to D7/D15) like an x86.Sorry for this hardware question, but I did not find any reference design on ARM bit numbering (or its reverse). Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more of the convention of documentation rather than technical, e.g. is A0/D0 the least significant or most significant.

Comment: Surely it's got a lot more to do with whatever flash controller is in your particular SoC/microcontroller? Unless perhaps you've got a 30-year-old monolithic Acorn ARM2 chip, the only thing you'd likely be "connecting" to an actual ARM CPU itself is hundreds of AHB/AXI signals at the RTL integration level. The programmer-visible data endianness between the CPU and the controller peripheral depends on the peripheral and could go either way - ARM CPUs can switch endianness freely; the signalling then from that peripheral to external pins is anyone's guess, without any documentation.

Comment: For NOR flash, the question matters as address/data lines are used to program the flash.  You need to read the data sheets to be sure.  For example if it is 16bit flash, it maybe A0(FLASH) -> A1(CPU).  It is likely that you can just change your constants and still have the flash work.  ARM should use D0-D7 for byte access, but as Notlikethat says 'what an external signal is' is not defined by ARM but by the SOC vendor (Atmel, Freescale/NXP, BroadCom, etc).  ARM defined signals will be internal to the chip.